# Why do blank lines appear after multi-level sorting?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that sorts by color, then by date, then again by date.

If I delete a date, instead of just re-sorting, it re sorts and then leaves blank rows where the row from which a date was deleted used to be.  I tried adding another sort layer where I sort by color RGB(0,0,0).

1. Why are the blank rows sitting there?
2. How do I remove them or make them not appear at all?

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:C")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("sorting")

    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("C:C"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, _
        xlDescending, _
        , _
        xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)

    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("C:C"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlDescending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal

   ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B:B"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlDescending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal

   ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2(Range("C:C"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, _
        xlDescending, _
        , _
        xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A:C")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End If
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I might have an answers to your questions, atleast for the second one I am sure...

## *Why are the blank rows sitting there?*

I can be only guessing since I do not have your source file to check for any irregularities nor your whole macro. If I had to guess, I would say it is either some function in your macro what is causing this or it might also be an issue of how you define sort ranges. You only specify columns and not actual starting cells and also no ending cells. The way I am used to sort data is to dynamically define the exact range.

## *How do I remove them or make them not appear at all?*

Please try the code which I have adjusted based on your data and code you provided:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:C")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("sorting")

With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<-- get last row of data in column "A"
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    
    .Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("C1:C" & lastRow), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlDescending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
    
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("B1:B" & lastRow), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("C1:C" & lastRow), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                        
    .Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("C1:C" & lastRow), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                        
    With .Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:C" & lastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End With

End If
```

The main adjustment is declaration of lastRow which adjusts the bottom of the data range (in your situation it should not matter but you might sometimes encounter data where you want to sort until certain row and this will be very helpful. Also lastRow as defined here is very helpful for a whole lot of other macros and helps to set ranges dynamically).

And I have also added the start the data as you can see in `Range("C1:C" & lastRow)`

I have tested this on a sample data you have provided and it worked as expected. I hope it will work for you exactly as you wanted to.

Comment: oh! and BTW that last sorting which you added (and I left in my code) which sorts RGB (255, 255, 255) means it sorts cells with **White** color. However, the blank cells you want to get rid of would have **No Fill** color that means instead of `.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)` you would likely want to use `.Color = xlNone`. Perhaps if you try this it could also pose a solution to your problem.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  Works like a charm on the sample data, going to try to integrate it into my actual spreadsheet.

Comment: One thing I changed- I swapped the second and third sorts, so it sorts by color, then by column C date, then by column B date.  That way, the green stuff is sorted by column C date, and that ordering is preserved when I sort by column B.